# Mounting an encrypted fs WITH prompt at boot time (LUKS, cryptsetup)

Tags: linux, debian, boot, luks

Per company policy my laptop has to be very secure in case of theft, so I have created an encrypted partition (LUKS) that I want to mount via `/etc/fstab`.

However, I do NOT want to add passphrase to the volume or use a key file (e.g. per [Auto mount encrypted partition using fstab without key prompts](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/mount-luks-encrypted-disk-partition-linux/#Auto_mount_encrypted_partition_using_fstab_without_key_prompts_for_LUKS_passphrase)), because I feel this is less secure than typing the passphrase at boot time.

I want to be asked for the passphrase at boot, the OS remembering it and automounting the volume (`/homeenc` in my case) during the boot so that I can log in at once to my user account with home dir located on that encrypted volume (say `/homeenc/example_user`).

While there's plenty of information on the web of how to automount LUKS device without entering password at boot, I can't find info on how to configure above.